# Index Out of Range Error When Creating SnowFlake Linked Service in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am passing the credentials and parameters required but I get the error

> The value of the property 'index' is invalid: 'Index was out of range.
> Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index'. Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
> and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
> Activity ID: 36a4265d-3607-4472-8641-332f5656661d.

Comment: Please include more information. I tried to reproduce how you might be getting that error but cannot.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I am getting the same error. The Azure portal doesn't provide any other information on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the UI doesn't generate the linked service correctly. Using [Microsoft Docs Example JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake) I received the same index error when attempting to create the linked service. If I remove the password from the connection string and add it as a separate property I am able to successfully generate the linked service.

**Microsoft Docs Example (Doesn't Work)**

```
{
    "name": "SnowflakeLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "type": "Snowflake",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": "jdbc:snowflake://<accountname>.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=<username>&password=<password>&db=<database>&warehouse=<warehouse>&role=<myRole>"
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "<name of Integration Runtime>",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

**Working Example**

```
{
    "name": "SnowflakeLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "type": "Snowflake",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": "jdbc:snowflake://<accountname>.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=<username>&db=<database>&warehouse=<warehouse>",
            "password": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "<password>"
            }
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "<name of Integration Runtime>",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the password contained a ' and that's causing the trouble. Changed the password with no symbols and it works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

We hit this same issue today, it was because our password had an ampersand (&) at the end. This seemed to mess up the connection string as it contained this:

```
&password=abc123&&role=MyRole
```

Changing the password to not include an ampersand fixed it

Comment: consider using URL-safe characters such as hyphen(-), period(.), underscore(_) and tilde(~) as speacial characters